# identify and count duplicate values across multiple columns

Tags: r, formatting

I have a dataset with multiple columns that look similar to this:

```
ID1     ID2     ID3      ID4
Blue    Grey    Fuchsia  Green
Black   Blue    Orange   Blue
Green   Green   Yellow   Pink
Pink    Yellow  NA       Orange
```

What I want to do is count how many times each value is duplicated across the four columns.   For example, this is what I'd like to get back from the above:

```
ID      Replicates   
Blue    3       
Black   1    
Green   3       
Pink    2
Grey    1
Yellow  2
Fuchsia 1 
Orange  2
```

I'd also like to be able to ask which ID value is present in the dataset at frequency >2. So the expected result would be: Green and Blue.

Any thoughts on how to do this in R?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a regular `table` is all you need for a data set full of factors.

```
> ( tab <- table(unlist(data)) )

  Black    Blue   Green    Pink    Grey  Yellow Fuchsia  Orange 
      1       3       3       2       1       2       1       2
```

Add `deparse.level = 2` if you want the table to be named.

It's easily subsetted with `[` indexing.  Just subset `tab` such that `tab` is greater than 2. And you can get the colors with `names`.

```
> tab[tab > 2]

 Blue Green 
    3     3 

> names(tab[tab > 2])
[1] "Blue"  "Green"
```

There's also an `as.data.frame` method.

```
> as.data.frame(tab)
     Var1 Freq
1   Black    1
2    Blue    3
3   Green    3
4    Pink    2
5    Grey    1
6  Yellow    2
7 Fuchsia    1
8  Orange    2
```

Answer (score 2):

a `dplyr` / `tidyr` solution

```
ID1<-c("Blue", "Black", "Green", "Pink")
ID2<-c("Grey", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow")
ID3<-c("Fuchsia", "Orange", "Yellow", NA)
ID4<-c("Green", "Blue", "Pink", "Orange")
mydf<-data.frame(ID1,ID2,ID3,ID4)


library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydf %>%
  gather(key,value,1:4) %>%
  group_by (value) %>%
  tally

    value n
1   Black 1
2    Blue 3
3 Fuchsia 1
4   Green 3
5    Grey 1
6  Orange 2
7    Pink 2
8  Yellow 2
9      NA 1
```

to return those at higher freq than 2...

```
mydf %>%
  gather(key,value,1:4) %>%
  group_by (value) %>%
  tally %>%
  filter (n>2)


  value n
1  Blue 3
2 Green 3
```

Comment: Compared to Scriven's approach this seems awfully Baroque.

Comment: Simple and effective approaches..thank you, gentlemen!